# I am looking how to store a result after completing a quiz CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I will try and make this as detailed as possible because ive been marked down before. There is a select quiz file outside of the codeigniter framework, it then takes you to 1 of 5 quizzes. Below is the computing quiz (each are the same apart from the questions and answers). The files below are stored in the view folder. The Play Quiz file is used to show all of the questions and answers. It gets the questions and answers from a database called multi_login and from a table called quiz. When the user has selected the answers and clicked submit, it will run the next block of code ive put down below. It uses arrays to check whether the answer is right or wrong, if it is right then it sets the background colour to green and adds 1 to score. The total of score is then displayed at the bottom of the quiz to show the users score. I have already used the model folders file at the bottom of the page, to select the table i want "quiz". I want to be able to store the score's number after the user has completed the quiz to be stored in a table called report into a column called score. Please help, i am using phpmyadmin for my database etc. I hope this is detailed enough, if not just comment.

Play Quiz code (for explanation):

```
<h1>Play the Computing Quiz!</h1>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Questions/resultdisplay">


<?php foreach($questions as $row) { ?>

<?php $ans_array = array($row->choice1, $row->choice2, $row->choice3, $row->answer);
shuffle($ans_array); ?>

<p><?=$row->question?></p>

<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?>" required> <?=$ans_array[0]?><br>
<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>"> <?=$ans_array[1]?><br>
<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>"> <?=$ans_array[2]?><br>
<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>"> <?=$ans_array[3]?><br>


<?php } ?>

<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">

</form>
```

After the submit button is clicked, it will sent the user to this page:

```
<h1>Play the Computing Quiz!</h1>

<?php $score =0; ?>

  <?php $array1= array(); ?>
  <?php $array2= array(); ?>    
  <?php $array3= array(); ?>
  <?php $array4= array(); ?>
  <?php $array5= array(); ?>
  <?php $array6= array(); ?>
  <?php $array7= array(); ?>
  <?php $array8= array(); ?>

     <?php foreach($checks as $checkans) { ?>
           <?php array_push($array1, $checkans); } ?>


    <?php foreach($results as $res) { ?>
           <?php array_push($array2, $res->answer); 
                 array_push($array3, $res->quizID); 
                 array_push($array4, $res->question); 
                 array_push($array5, $res->choice1); 
                 array_push($array6, $res->choice2); 
                 array_push($array7, $res->choice3); 
                 array_push($array8, $res->answer); 
           } ?>


       <?php 
           for ($x=0; $x <10; $x++) { ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/index">  


<p><?=$array4[$x]?></p>


  <?php if ($array2[$x]!=$array1[$x]) { ?>

       <p><span style="background-color: #FF9C9E"><?=$array1[$x]?></span></p>
       <p><span style="background-color: #ADFFB4"><?=$array2[$x]?></span></p>

  <?php } else { ?>

       <p><span style="background-color: #ADFFB4"><?=$array1[$x]?></span></p>

       <?php $score = $score + 1; ?>

<?php } } ?>

<br><br>

<p><b>Your Score: </b></p>
  <p><b><?=$score?>/10</b></p>

<input type="submit" value="Play Again!">

</form>
```

Model file:

```
class quizmodel extends CI_Model {

    public function getQuestions()
    {
        $this->db->select("quizID, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, answer, subject");
        $this->db->from("quiz");
        $this->db->where("subject",'computing');


        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();

        $num_data_returned = $query->num_rows;

        if ($num_data_returned < 1) {
          echo "There is no data in the database";
          exit();   
        }
    }
}
```

[Selecting Quiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgKwD.jpg)

[After selecting computing quiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMwQK.png)

[quiz image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bMEf.png)

[quiz image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgUDT.png)

[after clicking submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTCYo.png)

Comment: Just a bit of terminology: phpmyadmin is not a database server, it's just one (of many) user interface programs which can be used to interact with a MySQL database. Your database engine is MySQL, not phpmyadmin.

Comment: Anyway...are you asking how to use codeigniter to write an INSERT query? Or are you asking how to process the posted form data? What have you researched or tried so far?

Comment: Whatever works, I just want the score to be sent to a table called reports to a column called score

Comment: well making it work would probably involve both of the tasks I mentioned. It's unclear what part of it is giving you difficulty, other than perhaps you simply haven't given it much consideration? Both of which are quite researchable - inserting data is a very common task. So again, what have you researched or tried so far? We like to help people here, we like to fix problems in their code or explain a specific issue, but we're not a replacement for looking into the basic, well-documented concepts and then giving it a try.

Comment: Its incredibly annoying how rude people are on this. I have built the system this far I think I would have tried this section on my own and only be asking for help if i needed it. I used an INSERT but it did not work the way I did it. I am just unsure how to store the data after the submit button is clicked.

Comment: Just because there is probably a very easy and basic explanation for this doesnt mean you can assume i havent done my research. Some are just starting to learn PHP so its really annoying when we ask for help and its made to be a joke.

Comment: you haven't mentioned anything, you just said "I want to do it" and nothing more. Maybe it's just the way you worded it but it _sounds_ like you haven't given it any thought at all. I can't read your mind, I can only go off what you wrote here. If you researched something and tried it out, and had a problem, then please _show us_. That way we can either a) rule out an approach which failed and not waste time looking into it, or b) see that you just made a mistake and can fix it for you, without having to create the whole thing from scratch. Thanks.

Comment: We are volunteers here, we give our free time to try and help people. So a bit of reciprocation is appreciated. It's nice to help but it's annoying to keep repeating the same things and/or pointing people to information which is already freely available elsewhere.

Comment: So again...what specifically are you having difficulty with in this scenario?

Comment: maybe it would help if you add some screenies to that (basically the form) and your function `resultdisplay` in your `Questions` controller. But what i don't get is _There is a select quiz file outside of the codeigniter framework_ what does that mean ? (add a screenie of that as well)

Comment: also make sure you post your database structure. Furthermore your view `Play the Computing Quiz!` looks weird as well - i can't even figure out what you are doing here - as ADyson already said - we are certainly willing to help anybody - and you did most of the part right - you showed some effort, no doubt about that, but i'm not sure that you understand that there are missing parts which makes it impossible for us to retrace your problem.

Comment: I have added screenshots

Comment: I hope it is more explanatory now that after clicking submit in the quiz image 2, that the rest showed in the last screenshot would be sent to a table in a database, table name report, column name score.